# Create Formula based on cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to create a Match formula based on the Cells like the example bellow:

```
+------+--------+--------+
| Col1 | SumCol | Val    | 
+------+--------+--------+
|    1 |      8 | v1     | '=Match([otherWorkbook]MainSheet!C1,RC3,[otherWorkbook]MainSheet!C8)
|    2 |      5 | v44*   | '=Match([otherWorkbook]MainSheet!C2,RC3,[otherWorkbook]MainSheet!C5)
|    3 |      7 | ls*    | '=Match([otherWorkbook]MainSheet!C3,RC3,[otherWorkbook]MainSheet!C7)
+------+--------+--------+
```

To build the formula I need to get the string "[otherWorkbook]MainSheet" and concatenate with Cell from Column *Col1*. Then i need to get the value from Column *Val*. Finally I neet to concatenate again the string "[otherWorkbook]MainSheet" with cell from Column *SumCol*.

I expect a formula like `=Match([otherWorkbook]MainSheet!C1,RC3,[otherWorkbook]MainSheet!C8)`. I could make it using two temp Columns to make the concatenation and then, build the wole formula.

PS: I'm using VBA to make the formula, so i can use it to reach my goal.

Comment: If your in vba just combine the value of the cells into the formula string...

Comment: But I have like 5000 lines to fill. If I loop witch line the macro will take too long to complete the task. Thats why I want to create the formula and then `AutoFill()` - or just `Range(...).FormulaR1C1 =`

Comment: There is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like **this** :

```
Sub AddFormulas()

    myOtherWorkbook = "[otherWorkbook]"

    myFormula1 = "=Match(" & myOtherWorkbook & "MainSheet!C"
    myFormula2 = ",RC3," & myOtherWorkbook & "MainSheet!C"

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To lastRow  'Loops from row 2 to the last of column "A"

        Cells(x, 4).Formula = myFormula1 & Cells(x, 1) & myFormula2 & Cells(x, 2) & ")"

    Next x


End Sub
```